# How to group columns in a pivot?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

I have written the following code to create a `pivot grid` to display sales information about cars. It should generate a grid structure that is similar to the grid on the image

[image]

```js
var data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "make": "toyota",
        "model": "corolla",
        "fuelusagecity": "17",
        "fuelusagehwy": "12",
        "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
        "salesaboveavg": false,
        "totalnumberofsales": 120000.0000,
        "highsalestext": null,
        "salesdate": "2010-12-01"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "make": "toyota",
        "model": "corolla",
        "fuelusagecity": "10",
        "fuelusagehwy": "14",
        "salesaboveavg": false,
        "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
        "totalnumberofsales": 100000.0000,
        "highsalestext": "HIGH",
        "salesdate": "2010-12-15"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "make": "toyota",
        "model": "belta",
        "fuelusagecity": "15",
        "fuelusagehwy": "10",
        "salesaboveavg": true,
        "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
        "totalnumberofsales": 200000.0000,
        "highsalestext": null,
        "salesdate": "2011-01-10"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "make": "toyota",
        "model": "camry",
        "fuelusagecity": "13",
        "fuelusagehwy": "10",
        "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
        "salesaboveavg": false,
        "totalnumberofsales": 300000.0000,
        "highsalestext": "HIGH",
        "salesdate": "2011-04-23"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "make": "nissan",
        "model": "skyline",
        "fuelusagecity": "14",
        "fuelusagehwy": "9",
        "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
        "salesaboveavg": true,
        "totalnumberofsales": 500000.0000,
        "highsalestext": "HIGH",
        "salesdate": "2010-09-10"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "make": "nissan",
        "model": "zx300",
        "fuelusagecity": "10",
        "fuelusagehwy": "8",
        "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
        "salesaboveavg": false,
        "totalnumberofsales": 400000.0000,
        "highsalestext": null,
        "salesdate": "2012-01-06"
    }];

    /* convert the salesdate in  */
    var i, item, dateParts;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        if (typeof item.salesdate === "string") {
            dateParts = item.salesdate.split("-");
            item.salesYear = dateParts[0];
            item.salesMonth = dateParts[1];
            item.salesDay = dateParts[2];
            item.salesDateFormatted = dateParts[0];
        }
    }

    var myIntTemplate = {
        formatter: "currency",
        align: "right", sorttype: "number",
        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] },
        formatoptions: { defaultValue: ""}};

    $("#list483").jqGrid("jqPivot",
            data,
            {
                frozenStaticCols: true,
                skipSortByX: true,
                useColSpanStyle: true,
                //defaultFormatting: false,
                xDimension: [
                    { dataName: "make", width: 100, label: "Make" },
                    { dataName: "model", width: 100, label: "Model", align: "center", skipGrouping:true },
                    { dataName: "fuelmeasure", width: 103, label: "Units" },
                    ],
                yDimension: [
                    { dataName: "salesdate", sortorder: "desc"}//,
                    //{ dataName: "salesYear", sorttype: "integer" },
                    //{ dataName: "salesMonth", sorttype: "integer" }
                ],
                aggregates: [{
                    member: "totalnumberofsales",
                    template: myIntTemplate,
                    formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                       if(cellvalue=== undefined){
                           return '';
                       }
                        else{

                           var x = options.rowData.pivotInfos[options.colModel.name].rows[0].highsalestext;

                           if(x==="HIGH")
                           {
                               return x;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               return cellvalue;
                           }


                       }
                    },
                    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                        if (rawObject != null) {
                            var items = rawObject.pivotInfos[cm.name];
                            if (items != null && items.rows != null && items.rows.length > 0) {
                                var isHigh = true, i;
                                for (i = 0; i < items.rows.length; i++) {
                                    if (items.rows[i].highsalestext !== "HIGH") {
                                        isHigh = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (isHigh) {
                                    return "class='high-marker'";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    aggregator: "max"
                }/*,
                 {
                 member: "totalnumberofsales",
                 aggregator: "count",
                 //template: "integer",
                 label: "{0}"
                 }*/]
            },
            // grid options
            {
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, width: 75 },
                shrinkToFit: false,
                useUnformattedDataForCellAttr: false,
                autoResizing: { compact: true },
                groupingView: {
                    groupField: ["x0"],
                    groupColumnShow: [false],
                    groupText: ["<span class='group-text'>{0}</span>"]
                },
                //width: 450,
                pager: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                //caption: "<b>Car sales statistics</b>",
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, "10000:All"]
            }
    );

    jQuery("#list483").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'make', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<div style="display:inline-block">Min: <input type="text" id="minDate"  /> Max: <input type="text" id="miaxDate"  /></div>'}
    //{startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shiping'}
  ] 
});
```

Complete code for this can be found in this [Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/ocztddsd/3/). But when i apply the code to group the column headers with the following code lines:

```js
jQuery("#list483").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'make', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<div style="display:inline-block">Min: <input type="text" id="minDate"  /> Max: <input type="text" id="miaxDate"  /></div>'}
    //{startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shiping'}
  ] 
});
```

it does not group columns as expected. why is that and how do i fix this?

wish you all a happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that column grouping isn't correct way in you case. I sugget you to add `toolbar: [true, "top"]` option to the grid options to create an empty toolbar on top of the grid. The toolbar will have the `id` build from `"t_"` prefix and the id of the grid. Thus you can add any custom content to the toolbar by usage the code like below

```js
$('<div style="display:inline-block">Min: <input type="text" id="minDate"  /> Max: <input type="text" id="miaxDate"  /></div>').appendTo("#t_list483");
```

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/ocztddsd/4/

Comment: i have marked this as answer but stackoverflow wont let me give votes for it.

Comment: @Dore.Ad: It's no problem! The most important that your problem is solved. You will get the right to vote about 30 questions or answers **per day** after  arrival 15 points of reputation points.